# Non-interactively create one partition with all available disk size

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk

This is disgusting to me, but it works:

```
echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nt\nc\na\n1\nw" | fdisk /dev/sdb
```

I would like to know a more prudent or elegant way to accomplish this.  The entire boot record and partition table is being zeroed prior to this task, so we can trust that partition 1 is available.

Comment: It's also possible to write that same 'echo' on multiple lines (if you're doing it in a bash script) - same level of 'disgusting', but slightly more readable. Better options in the answers below though :-)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [**parted**](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html) which can be used in command line mode for scripting. [**sfdisk**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk) can also be scripted but note the caveats about GPTs and partition sizes.

Comment: I'm sure it's in here somewhere, but I'm having a hard time finding how you can specify to use all of the available space.

Answer (score 6):

**`sfdisk`**

```
echo 'start=2048, type=83' | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdX
```

should fill a disk with a single partition.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/332252/creating-and-formating-a-partition-using-a-bash-script/1132834#1132834 for a detailed explanation of the command syntax, including the `type=83` part and more.